# How to call to get a single gps fix when ever i want android?

Tags: android, gps, location

How can I get a single GPS fix of my location just by calling one function? Just for this example how can I get the Lat and Lon into a toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Here are two of the official pages for location: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

But to get the most recent location and show it in a Toast:

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
String lat = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
String longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
Toast.makeText(context, lat+","+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you want to request a new location, it is more code, and I will not cover that here. You can do some google searching or searching on here to find how to use it. The method you need is `requestLocationUpdates` or `requestSingleUpdate`. I'm guessing you would prefer `requestSingleUpdate`

Comment: Note that `getLastKnownLocation()` for GPS can return `null` if GPS hasn't been used recently.  If coarse accuracy is ok, one might want to try getting last known location from multiple providers.  Solution for multiple providers is here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365895/937715.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can just make one call and get a location fix. GPS / Android just doesn't work that way. The phone *may* have a last known location, but that last known location may have been taken/recorded hours ago and miles away. The location returned by the getLastKnownLocation() method has a time stamp and an accuracy that can be used to see if the location is "good enough".

Locations are typically determined by setting up a listener, listening for updates and stopping the listener when you have a good enough fix. See [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) for a good worked example, especially the details in the example isBetterLocation() method.

I find it best to create an Asynchronous task that actively registers and deregisters GPS/network/passive listeners depending on whether the application has a good enough location, or not, and have that class export a getMyPosition() method that returns a Location object if a good enough position has been established, or null if not. Then the main code *can* make a simple one line function call to get the current position. But only because there is an asynch task behind the scenes doing the hard work.

I try to make my asynch task actively deregister the GPS listener and turn off the GPS circuits to save battery live when I have a good enough fix. How long I turn off the listeners depends on the needs of the application. Leaving the passive listener left on (registered) allows my task/application to listen into the GPS position reports caused by any other application on the device "for free".

Getting a good enough position is not a one function call deal, unless you make it so with lots of behind the scenes work.