# android Refresh current Location

Tags: android, sms, position, refresh

In my application I want to receive SMS and afert that, I want to get the the location of the phone and when I have the location, I want to send it By SMS...

by now, there is what I have :

```
package com.receiver;  
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.ComponentName;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{  

   private final String ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS  = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";  
   private String numero;  
   private String msg;  

   @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){  
    Log.i("ReceiveBootCompleted","****** Boot terminer ********************");  
    Log.i("ReceiveBootCompleted"," ***** lancement du service Test **************");  
    context.startService(new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), SMSReceiver.class.getName())));  

   if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS)){  
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  
        if (bundle != null){  
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");  
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];  
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){  
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);  
            }  
            if (messages.length > -1){  
                final String messageBody = messages[0].getMessageBody();  
                final String phoneNumber = >messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();  
                if(messageBody.equals("mollo")){  
                    app.smartfinder.SmartFinderActivity.send_message(phoneNumber);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  

}
```

and : 
    package app.smartfinder;

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.util.List;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.location.Address;  
import android.location.Geocoder;  
import android.location.Location;  
import android.location.LocationListener;  
import android.location.LocationManager;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.text.Html;  
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.view.Window;  
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class SmartFinderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {  
    LocationManager lm;  
    private Location location;  
    private double lat = 0;  
    private double lng = 0;  
    TextView position;  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){  

   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

   lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);  
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);  
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);  
        position = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.var_current_pos);  
    }  

   public void onClick_conf(View view){  
        Toast.makeText(SmartFinderActivity.this, "config", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),               Preferences.class);  
        startActivity(settingsActivity);  
    }  
   public void onClick_hist (View view){  
        Toast.makeText(SmartFinderActivity.this, "history", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }  

   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  

    lat = location.getLatitude();  
       lng = location.getLongitude();  
        afficherAdresse();  

   position.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) {  
                Intent intent_map = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Map.class);  
                intent_map.putExtra("lat", lat);  
                intent_map.putExtra("lng", lng);  
                startActivity(intent_map);  
            }  
        });  
    lm.removeUpdates(this);  
    }  
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }  
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }  
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {  
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }  

   public void afficherAdresse() {  
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(SmartFinderActivity.this);  
        try {  
            List<Address> adresses = geo.getFromLocation(lat,lng,1);  

   if(adresses != null && adresses.size() == 1){  
                Address adresse = adresses.get(0);  
                //if geocoder find a adresse, we can use it  
                position.setText( adresse.getAddressLine(0) + " " + adresse.getPostalCode() + " " + adresse.getLocality());  
            }  
            else {  
                //else: no adress  
                position.setText("L'adresse n'a pu être déterminée");  
            }  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            position.setText("L'adresse n'a pu être déterminée");  
        }  
    }  

   public static void send_message(String phoneNumber) {  

   // `refresh Location : that's the problem ! ` 

   // send method : not difficult  

 }  
 }
```

My problem is that I want to refresh my position when method "send_message" is called.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're asking how to get your current location when you receive an SMS message so that you can send back the current location in another SMS message. I think that you are assuming that your are able to just make a call to get your current location to report back.

GPS doesn't work that way. It needs to run for a little while to get enough messages from enough satellites to be able to determine a position and an accuracy for that position. So there is no single function call to simply get the device location instantly.

Instead it is necessary to run a background task (I use an Async Task) to listen to position updates and the iterate to the current location. My task turns off the listening (and the GPS hardware) when it has a good enough fix to save battery life.

See [a previous related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8620415/819612) for more information.

It is possible to ask the Location Manager for the current position. However, this is the last position that it recorded. If no application has used the GPS hardware for a while then that postion fix could be very old and therefore not accurate at all. At work, my building shields the GPS signals (metal cladding) and so my phone currently believes that it is at my home many miles away which is where I last used a GPS enabled app.

As SMS takes a variable time to be delivered I think that it is probably correct to take a few extra seconds to fire off the GPS collection and wait for a good enough fix before responding. SMS is not an instant delivery vehicle so the extra few seconds delay in getting a good fix will not add much to the round-trip time of your SMS messages.